# can one stop spam with my name but not my address

Tags: spam

IS there a way to stop getting spam that is from my name but not my e mail address  I am receiving many spam letters using my name but different e mail addresses.

Comment: Have you tried switching on your provider's and your mail client's anti-spam systems?  Most of them learn their mistakes when you mark an email as spam so do that and it will get better at blocking.

Comment: If you're getting spam to an address that isn't yours, are you pointing a catch-all email addresses to your inbox?  If so, stopping using a catch all would probably help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to filter spam messages. First of all, check if your email provider has enabled spam filter for your account. There is a lot of anti-spam techniques which can be employ to help your problem:

- RBL,
- URIBL,
- SPF,
- greylisting,

and a lot of others.

On the other hand, if you are using local email client you can install some anti-spam plugin:

- http://www.specificfeeds.com/blog/the-best-free-spam-filters-for-outlook-thunderbird-and-outlook-express/
- http://email.about.com/od/outlookspamfilters/tp/anti-spam_ol.htm
- https:__addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/emailsecurityplus/